# View how much ram my videocard has in Win7

Tags: windows-7

How can I see how much RAM my videocard has in Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's like Vista then you need to navigate to "Control Panel", "Performance Information and Tools" then click "View and Print details"

Update: yes it's the same on my Win 7 netbook. You might need to change Control Panel's view to "small icons" to easily find "performance Information and Tools".

Comment: I'm with you on this one, DxDiag shows "Approx. Total Memory: 3797MB" for my 1GB Graphics card while Performance Information show me 1GB dedicated and 2.7GB shared memory.  The 1GB is what is on the card, 3.7GB is what is available *to the system* for the graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way is to use the DirectX Diagnostic tool.
simply type

> dxdiag

into the search field in the start menu.
dxdiag should come up as an option. run the program and view the "Display" tab.
the display tab provids information on your video card.
there is a line named "Approx. Total Memory:" this line holds the ram on your video card.

Comment: On my netbook that gives Approx Total memory. Performance Indicator & Tools also breaks it down into Dedicated Graphics Memory, Dedicated System Memory and Shared System Memory.

Comment: in my OP Performance Indicator & Tools can be misleading and confusing as it is concerned with the memory of the entire system. thats why I suggested dxdiag, as it is only concerned with the video card. but yes, if you want to know the details of how memory is allocated on the system use Performance Indicator & Tools

Answer (score 0):

Use [GPU-z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)

[image]